# How do the packages color, xcolor, and colortbl differ? How do they relate to each other?

Tags: tables, color

Question itself is pretty easy.

However I've found a few packages like

- colortbl
- color
- xcolor

I am a bit confused about differences between them, and about which of them fits this problem better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `color` and `xcolor` packages both provide -- you guessed it! -- general color-related capabilities to a LaTeX document. Unless you're strongly vested in the `color` package, I would recommend you use the more recent, and more capable, `xcolor` package.

The `colortbl` package provides -- you guessed right again!! -- macros and environments for coloring rows, columns, and cells of `tabular`-like environments. To maximize interoperability between `xcolor` and `colortbl`, you should *not* load them separately and independently. Instead, use the directive

```
\usepackage[table,<other-options,-if-any>]{xcolor}
```

to load both packages. See page 9 of the user guide of the `xcolor` package for the list of options recognized by the `xcolor` package.